# Передача изображения в виде файла

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Есть в приложении mvc страничка на которой есть `input type file`. Пользователь в него добавляет изображение. Далее я передаю на сервер и сохраняю в базу данных. Есть возможность например передать в виде файла и хранить в blob поле. При редактировании я буду передавать файл назад, для того что бы отобразить на странице какое изображение у редактируемой записи? Как можно записать этот файл в `input type file` для того что бы там не было написано что "Файл не выбран", а как будто пользователь его выбирал.

Comment: ни как нельзя так

Comment: лучше хринет не фалйв базе а его путь по которому он сохранен насервере и возвращайте этот путь  это на нмого лучше